# How to select specific information in a specific object from an array of objects using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object

I am currently finishing an online full-stack course that requires me to make an e-commerce store as my final project. A part of the project's instructions is to add an "add to cart" function where I must use Vue.js.

I currently have an array of objects like such:

```js
const shop =[
    {
        id : 1,
        name: "Spotify Plaque",
        price: 150,
        quantity: 0
    },
    {
        id : 2,
        name: "Keychain",
        price: 35,
        quantity: 0
    },
    {
        id : 3,
        name: "Cards",
        price: 30,
        quantity: 0
    },
    {
        id : 4,
        name: "Spotify Keychain",
        price: 35,
        quantity: 0
    },
    {
        id : 5,
        name: "Mugs",
        price: 70,
        quantity: 0
    },
    {
        id : 6,
        name: "Glass Cups",
        price: 70,
        quantity: 0
    },
    {
        id : 7,
        name: "Round Christmas Baubles",
        price: 45,
        quantity: 0
    },
    {   
        id : 8,
        name: "Flat Christmas Baubles",
        price: 30,
        quantity: 0
    }
]
```

And I have a product display like such (using bootstrap):

```html
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="./assets/images/spotifykeychain.jpg" class="card-img-top rounded" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Product Name Go Here</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Product Price Go Here</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="bi bi-cart-plus"></i> Add to Cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My question is, is there any way that I can display the information in the objects in my array, but specifically choose which object and what information in that object I want to display, all using Vue.js?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Comment: Thank you for your response @AnujRaghuvanshi , I appreciate your attempt at helping me learn. I hope I am not sounding too ignorant when I ask this but, how would I go about using conditionals to specifically target information in an object within an array?

Comment: You will be using repeat to show a list of your products. And you will have access to objects in your repeat section. So you can put a condition on your object.


Have you added the logic of showing all products list? After adding that, You will get cleared on my above words.

Comment: I haven't added the logic of showing all the products as they are all objects in an array and I specifically am struggling with extracting the objects and their contents from the array and displaying their information in my designed div. Is using a loop the only way that I can display the objects in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes basically Vue.js does that very perfectly. you can iterate through the array and choose what do display, whats powerful is you can incorporate even the `if-statement`

Below is just an example using your array and html codes

```
     <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 d-flex justify-content-center" v-for ="prod in shop" :key = "prod.id">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="./assets/images/spotifykeychain.jpg" class="card-img-top rounded" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{prod.name}}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">usd {{prod.price}}</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="bi bi-cart-plus"></i> Add to Cart {{prod.quantity}}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This seems like it will be very useful and I appreciate your attempt in helping me learn. I am going to try and use your example and implement it, I will report my results and any further questions I have!

Comment: Welcome any time, if this answer helps you. you can vote it up :)

Comment: And its two brackets not one.. its {{ }} not { }

Comment: apologies if this follow-up seems a bit ignorant but I am failing to display anything still. My question is, what does the 'prod' in v-for="prod in shop" do and where does it come from?

Comment: okey... shop is your array,.... then v-for loop on every object on that array and on each iteration that object is assigned to variable prod. so using prod you can display the content of that iteration

Comment: I got it to work, you were a big help! Thank you!

Comment: Yes, finish that course, get good and lets tackle these problems as community of coders :)